# setTimeout not executing as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched this quite a bit, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have an ASP.NET page with jQuery referenced (no errors) and the below script:

```
$(function () {
  $('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click(function () {
    debugger;
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#Success').css("visibility", "visible");
      $('#Def').css("visibility", "hidden");
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  })
});
```

The idea is to hide one panel and show another one on button click. I added `debugger` and saw that it is indeed called. However it seems like the code block after it is simply skipped as it does not perform the function and returns false.

Can anyone help me out on this one?

Edit 1
    
     Complete

```
<asp:Panel ID="Def" runat="server">
Default panel
</asp:Panel>
```

Changed the code above for the panel as below but an error occurs

```
            $('#Success').style.display ="block";
            $('#Def').style.display = "none";
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've shown - it works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/bd5s4dey/. Check the console for errors, and also ensure that you don't have any existing CSS which is interfering.

Comment: Of course it "jumps over it" because it takes 1 second until the timeout triggers. Have you tried putting the breakpoint inside the timeout function?

Comment: The function inside setTimeout will be executed after 1000ms, it's normal that you not jump into it!

Comment: Thanks - yes it does enter the block. Any reason why the panels are not hidden/shown? Ive amended my code above under edit 1. Thanks for those who downvoted me without any reason to explain themselves!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
 $('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click(function () {
  debugger;
  setTimeout(function () {
     $('#Success').css("display", "");
     $('#Def').css("display", "none");
}, 1000);
return false;
 })
});
```

this will work...